# Caliburn.Micro Action Message with StaticResource as parameter

Tags: caliburn.micro

How can i convert this long format to short inline format. I tried with various combinations but none worked. I always get the parameter as null.

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="GotFocus">
        <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="SelectTool">
           <cal:Parameter Value="{StaticResource contrastTool}" />
        </cal:ActionMessage>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

I tried with this:

```
cal:Message.Attach="[Event GotFocus] = [Action SelectTool({StaticResource contrastTool})]"
```

but this doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be solved using Caliburn.Micro Contrib (also available via Nuget).

To enable XamlBinding, insert below code in your bootstrapper

```
FrameworkExtensions.Message.Attach.AllowExtraSyntax(MessageSyntaxes.SpecialValueProperty | MessageSyntaxes.XamlBinding);
```

Then in Xaml you may use

```
cal:Message.Attach="[Event GotFocus] = [Action SelectTool({StaticResource contrastTool})]"
```

Comment: Do not use this library. It does not work with Caliburn Micro 2.0.2 and it messes up your whole project references. I lost hours because of this.